# Sending CSV data to BigQuery REST API via POST

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I've been trying to upload a `*.csv` blob via POST request to BigQuery, but I'm having trouble determining where should I put the blob file (i.e. byte data) in the request.

If I use a client library, this code does what I need:

```
var job = {
  configuration: {
    load: {
      destinationTable: {
        projectId: projectId,
        datasetId: datasetId,
        tableId: tableId
      },
      skipLeadingRows: 1,
      allowQuotedNewlines: true,
      quote: "'",
      sourceFormat: 'CSV'
    }
  }
};
var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, csv);
```

This works perfectly, but while searching through the REST API, I don't see declared anywhere where to set the `*.csv` data in order to work like this, with no client library:

```
var job = {
  configuration: {
    load: {
      destinationTable: {
        projectId: projectId,
        datasetId: datasetId,
        tableId: tableId
      },
      skipLeadingRows: 1,
      allowQuotedNewlines: true,
      quote: "'",
      sourceFormat: 'CSV'
    }
  }
};
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/" + projectId + "/jobs/";
var urlParams = {
  "method": "POST",
  "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " + getBQToken()},
  "responseType": "json",
  payload: job,
};
var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, urlParams).getContentText();
var result = JSON.parse(resp);
```

How can I include my CSV data and the job configuration when using the REST API approach?

Comment: Does the [documentation on uploads](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#uploads) help?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to make upload requests: multipart upload and resumable upload. Multipart upload is “for quick transfer of smaller files and metadata; transfers the file along with metadata that describes it, all in a single request”. Resumable upload is “for reliable transfer, especially important with larger files” as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#uploads) (as @Elliott Brossard pointed). Find in the same documentation the resumable upload request for the Google BigQuery API example below:

```
POST /upload/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectId>/jobs?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: */*
X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000

{
  "configuration": {
    "load": {
      "sourceFormat": "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
      "schema": {
        "fields": [
          {"name": "f1", "type": "STRING"},
          {"name": "f2", "type": "INTEGER"}
        ]
      },
      "destinationTable": {
        "projectId": "projectId",


  "datasetId": "datasetId",
    "tableId": "tableId"
  }
}
```

}
}